# Plotting data cubes

Tags: view, plot, data-warehouse, olap-cube, data-cube

Is there a way to plot data cubes with any kind of program? In order to plot this ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2vrX.png)) image, I had to use [TinkerCard](https://www.tinkercad.com), that by the way doesn't allow to put names along the data cube dimensions. Is there any kind of tool that allows do do something similar to ([2](http://okfnlabs.org/img/posts/olap-slice_and_dice-overview.png)) or ([3](http://www.businessperform.com/images/feature/diag_people_data_cube.png))? Thanks in advance

[image: Data Cube View]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a not possible.

The cubes which I play with all have atleast 10 dimensions.
The problem is that the short name, `olap cube`, suggests that some sort of pictorial representation is possible.
I think it is maybe better to remeber them using the fuller name `multi-dimensional cubes`. 
Once past 3 dimensions I don't understand how it will be possible to draw a representative picture.

Saying all the above I have a book co-authored by Mosha Pasumadsky which contains some simple cube pictures similar to your picture. Also I attended a course run by Chris Webb and he used pictures of cubes to help our understanding. The pictures they have used are all very simplified, and of only small spaces within a full cube.